# Cannot build APK file after migrate from GCM to FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apk

I have just migrate app from GCM to FCM, app can run and debug normally but when build apk file, the error show following :

**Duplicate files copied in APK res/layout/notification_action.xml
File1: D:\Plus-Android\PlusMuse\build\jarjar\jarjar-20.jar
File2: D:\Plus-Android\PlusMuse\build\jarjar\jarjar-21.jar**

I have search any websites and forum in order to find out solution but still can't help.
My dependencies :
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

```
compile jarjar.repackage {
    from 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'

    classDelete "com.google.android.gms.common.util.VisibleForTesting.class"
}
compile jarjar.repackage {
    from 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'

    classDelete "android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner.class"
}

compile project(':libs:com_actionbarsherlock')
compile project(':libs:holoEverywhereLib')
compile project(':libs:recoMediaLibrary')
compile project(':libs:preLollipopTransition')
compile project(':lyrimokit')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

My packagingOptions

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    classpath "org.anarres.jarjar:jarjar-gradle:1.0.0"
}
```

So, anybody can help me to find out solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to file in android studio and  do Invalidate cache/restart.

Comment: I have just tried but this new error show :

Cause: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/FractionRes.class